# Not able to parse JSON format logs

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to parse the JSON format logs which I have saved in a simple file , but getting error , seems like my records are not recognized as JSON.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val out = getContent("file")
  val parsedLogs = JSON.parseFull(out) match {
    case Some(x) => {
      x.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]]
    }
  }
  for (log <- parsedLogs) {
         //do stuff
  }

def getRestContent(url: String): String = {
  scala.io.Source.fromFile(url).mkString
}
```

Logs are inconsistent , that is every log can be of different event, some sample logs are

```
{"Event":"SparkListenerLogStart","Spark Version":"2.1.0.43"}
{"Event":"SparkListenerBlockManagerAdded","Block Manager ID":{"Executor 
ID":"driver","Host":"127.0.0.0","Port":9090},"Maximum 
Memory":956615884,"Timestamp":1499927973730}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to give us more of the code and show us what error you are getting.

Comment: The sample log you've pasted is not valid JSON. If there are multiple objects they need to be wrapped in an array, like so: `[{"a": 1"}, {"b": 2}]`. Also, provide the error you're getting.

Comment: What is `out`? Where is `parsedLogs`? Can you post the full code? and the exact error message. Are you parsing each event (each line is probably valid json) or trying to parse the whole file as JSON (which is probably not valid json as a whole).

Comment: @Michael I tried to wrap in an array , but the error persisted

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Broadly saying the error is "Cannot cast immutable List to immutable Map"